# Excel Save as PDF creates two different size files on different computers (Vector image problem too)

Tags: excel, pdf, save

I have a little problem that I've haven't found a solution yet, my theory is that it related to the  GPU or CPU difference between computers, or the office version, home on the work, en pro in my personal computers.

When I save as pdf an excel report that I created in my work computer (notebook Lenovo Thinkpad, I5-7200U, Intel HD Graphic 620) the file size is around 911 kb and the vector images that I have in the file are created as images in the resulting PDF document.

[Resulting image in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woBBe.png)

As in my personal computer, intel I7-9700k, Nvidia GTX 1070 TI and personal notebook (intel I7-7700HQ, Nvidia GTX 1070 Mobile). The file size is around 455 kb and the resulting image from the vector (svg) in the excel maintains its vector property.

[Resulting image in PDF 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ORjl.png)

I tried changing the default printer to "microsoft print to pdf" as a read in another place, but nothing changed, I figure, since I'm saving as pdf from "save as" and not printing to save as PDF.

Comment: @Chrimle office from work Standard 2016, personal one professional plus 2016.

Comment: @KJ one results in an image onto the pdf and the other results in a vector image on the pdf. And the settings are the same in both cases, quality normal (1).

Comment: @KJ I'm using the option save as "PDF", not printing them into PDF if I do that in both cases the resulting image is not a vector image.

Comment: I tried saving the pdf with the microsoft print to pdf and with export, and the image with print to pdf is of lower quality than the one with the export  option, but still are not vector as in my personal computer. I also tried chaging the advance options 330 dpi and to not compress the image in file and high quality mode for graphics and it didn't change.

Comment: I change my work computer for one with a T500 quadro thinkpad 14s with office 2019 Standard, and in this new computer the vector images results in vector images in the PDF.